# NullPointerException thrown when Mocking a service method call (from an internal forEach loop), what is the correct way to implement this mock?

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, testng, junit4

I have a very basic Spring Boot application.
It consists of a `Controller` a `Service` and a `Repository`.
I want to test the `Controller` which basically just calls the `Service`, which in turn calls the `Repository`.
I'm trying to mock the `Service` and inject it into the `Controller` for testing, but it fails at this row:

```
when(service.findEntry(1L)).thenReturn(model);
```

The error is `NullPointerException` and when I go through the stack trace it's because of a `HashSet.forEach()` call.
How can I fix this? In the row above the method `service.findEntry(1L)` is actually called and throws a `NullPointerException`
The Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.efl.journal.controller.JournalEntryControllerITests.testGetJournalEntryById(JournalEntryControllerITests.java:46)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1$1.evaluate(DefaultInternalRunner.java:44)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner$1.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:74)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.DefaultInternalRunner.run(DefaultInternalRunner.java:80)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.StrictRunner.run(StrictRunner.java:39)
    at org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:163)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

My Test Class:

```
package com.efl.journal.controller;

import com.efl.journal.model.JournalEntryModel;
import com.efl.journal.service.JournalEntryService;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;


import java.util.HashSet;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertEquals;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class JournalEntryControllerITests {

    @MockBean
    JournalEntryService service;

    @InjectMocks
    JournalEntryController controller;

    @Test
    public void testGetJournalEntryById(){
        JournalEntryModel model = new JournalEntryModel();
        model.setEntryId(1L);
        model.setSubject("test 1");
        model.setBody("This is a test");
        model.setUserId(1L);
        model.setTags(new HashSet<>());

        when(service.findEntry(1L)).thenReturn(model);
        Response result = controller.getJournalEntry(1L);
        JournalEntryModel resultModel = (JournalEntryModel) result.getEntity();

        assertEquals(model.getEntryId(), resultModel.getEntryId());
    }
}
```

My `Controller`:

```
package com.efl.journal.controller;

import com.efl.journal.model.JournalEntryModel;
import com.efl.journal.service.JournalEntryService;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
@Slf4j
public class JournalEntryController {

    JournalEntryService entryService;

    @Autowired
    public JournalEntryController(JournalEntryService entryService){
        this.entryService = entryService;
    }


    @GetMapping("entry/{entryId}")
    public Response getJournalEntry(@PathVariable Long entryId){
        JournalEntryModel journalEntry =  entryService.findEntry(entryId);
        if( journalEntry != null){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                    .entity(journalEntry)
                    .build();
        }

        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                    .build();
    }

    @GetMapping("entry")
    public Response getAllJournalEntires(){
        List<JournalEntryModel> entryList = entryService.findAllEntryObjects();

        if(entryList.isEmpty()){
            return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT).build();
        }
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(entryList).build();
    }

    @PostMapping("entry")
    public Response postJournalEntry(@RequestBody JournalEntryModel entry) {
        entry = entryService.saveJournalEntry(entry);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(entry)
                .build();
    }

    @DeleteMapping("entry/{entryId}")
    public Response deleteJournalEntry(@PathVariable Long entryId, @RequestBody JournalEntryModel entry ){
        entryService.deleteJournalEntry(entry);
        return Response.status(Response.Status.NO_CONTENT)
                .build();
    }
}
```

My `Service` class:

```
package com.efl.journal.service;

import com.efl.journal.entity.JournalEntry;
import com.efl.journal.model.JournalEntryModel;
import com.efl.journal.repository.JournalEntryRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class JournalEntryService {

    private JournalEntryRepository journalEntryRepo;

    @Autowired
    public JournalEntryService(JournalEntryRepository journalEntryRepo){
        this.journalEntryRepo = journalEntryRepo;
    }

    public JournalEntryModel findEntry(Long id) {
        Optional<JournalEntry> optional = journalEntryRepo.findById(id);
        if(optional.isPresent()){
            return optional.get().toModel();
        }

        return null;

    }

    public List<JournalEntryModel> findAllEntryObjects(){
        Iterable<JournalEntry> iterable = journalEntryRepo.findAll();
        Iterator iterator = iterable.iterator();

        List<JournalEntryModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

        iterator.forEachRemaining(e -> {
               list.add(((JournalEntry) e).toModel());
        });

        return list;
    }

    public JournalEntryModel saveJournalEntry(JournalEntryModel entry){
        return journalEntryRepo.save(entry.toEntity()).toModel();
    }

    public void deleteJournalEntry(JournalEntryModel entry){
        journalEntryRepo.delete(entry.toEntity());
    }

    public List<JournalEntryModel> findEntriesbyUserId(Long userId){
        return null;
    }

}
```

My JournalEntity class:

```
package com.efl.journal.entity;

import com.efl.journal.model.JournalEntryModel;
import com.efl.journal.model.TagModel;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.hibernate.annotations.ColumnDefault;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "entry")
@Getter
@Setter
public class JournalEntry implements Serializable {

    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    private Long entryId;
    private Long userId;
    private String subject;
    private String body;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @ColumnDefault("CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    private LocalDateTime localDateTime;
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "journal_entry_tags",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name="entry_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name= "tag_id")}
    )
    private Set<Tag> tags = new HashSet<>();

    public JournalEntry(){
    }

    public JournalEntryModel toModel(){
        JournalEntryModel entry = new JournalEntryModel();
        entry.setEntryId(entryId);
        entry.setUserId(userId);
        entry.setSubject(subject);
        entry.setBody(body);
        entry.setLocalDateTime(localDateTime);
        Set<TagModel> tagModels = new HashSet<>();
        tags.forEach(t->{
            tagModels.add(t.toModel());
        });
        entry.setTags(tagModels);

        return entry;
    }
}
```

I think the error occurs with the call of `JournalEntity.toModel()` method call. But I don't understand why this method is actually called when it's part of the code in the method I'm trying to mock.

Comment: I was using the wrong annotation, should have been `@Mock` not `@MockBean` , see see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test is a unit test, run with the Mockito runner, which doesn't care at all about the Spring MockBean annotation. It should be annotated with Mockito's `@Mock` method, not with `@MockBean`.